# What is special in "2000 ama" that it have the unique note

Tags: commentaries, pentateuch-chumash, trop-cantillation

What is special in the words "2000 ama" in the verce numbers [35.5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.35.5) that is has a [conitasinal note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karne_parah) that is unique in thw chumash (only found once)

Onther places in the bible that it is found
(במדבר לה ה
 ([יהושוע יט נא](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.19.51) , [שמואל-ב ד ב](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.4.2) , [מלכים-ב י ה](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.10.5), ירמיהו יג יג , ירמיהו לח כה, יחזקאל מח כא , דברי הימים-א כח א , דברי הימים-ב כד ה , דברי הימים-ב לה ז , אסתר ז ט ,עזרא ו ט , נחמיה א ו , נחמיה ה יג , נחמיה יג ה , נחמיה יג טו))

I guess my question is what does medrash/kabala/chasiduss say about it